# Select the most recent value based on a given date

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

In Access I Use this dummy table(table1) and I want  to update a field of the table2 with the logic displayed below. Eg for ID=1 all the values of field2 in table2 should have the value 10 while the Date is <1/1/2015 and all the values after that date should have the value 8 and so on.

```
Table1
ID    field1      reviewDate
1        10       1/1/2014    
1        8        1/1/2015
2        5        3/3/2013
2        6        4/4/2014
2        4        5/5/2015

Table2
ID    field2     Date
 1     10         1/1/2014
 1     10         2/1/2014
 .       .          .
 .       .          .
 1      8         1/1/2015
```

I've tried a select statement instead first to see how close I am to the desired results and it is the following:

```
select a.ID, field1, max(reviewDate) as max , b.Date 
from table1 a  
inner join table2 b 
on a.ID=b.ID 
and b.Date >=a.reviewDate
group by ID,field1,reviewDate,Date 
order by a.ID,b.Date
```

The problem obviously is that when the Date is greater than both the reviewDates of the same ID returns both values for the same Date. I want only the contemporary. eg for ID=1 on the date=2/1/2015 field2=8 only but in my script for the Date=2/1/2015 I have two records 10 and 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, probably not the most efficient, still a solution though.

I store the ID,Date and the corresponding reviewDate in a working/temp table. using this query:

```
select a.ID,a.Date,max(ReviewDate) as RevDate 
into temp1 
from table1 a 
inner join table2 b on a.ID=b.ID and a.Date>=b.ReviewDate 
group by a.ID,a.Date
```

Then I add an extra column to my table2 , ReviewDate column, update the values  joining the temp1 table

```
update table2 a 
inner join temp1 b on a.ID=b.ID and a.date=b.date 
set a.reviewDate=b.RevDate
```

and then I update the field2 values joining the table1 on ID,date and reviewDate.

```
update table2 a 
inner join table1 b
on a.ID=b.ID and a.Date=b.Date and a.ReviewDate=b.Reviewdate 
set a.field2=b.field1
```

I guess some steps can be merged but I didn't have the time to check it properly. Feel free to give a more efficient solution. Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

I would just do this with a correlated subquery:

```
select t2.*,
       (select top 1 t1.field1
        from table1 t1
        where t1.id = t2.id and t1.reviewDate <= t2.Date
        order by t1.reviewDate desc, t1.field1
       ) as field1
from table2 as t2;
```

Comment: I tried to run this but I received this error message: "At most one record can be returned by this subquery"

Comment: @kostas . . . That means that a given `id` can have more than one review date.  I added `field1` to the `order by` to get around this.  However, a unique row would be the best approach.

Comment: That is correct. Now when I run your updated script  the following weird thing happens. The script is executed successfully, brings the datasheet results normally and after a few seconds the same error message pops "At most one record can be returned by this subquery" erasing every value from the table.. Did you just break Access Gordon?:)

Comment: @kostas . . . You need to add columns to the `order by` to make the key unique.  I'm not sure what such a key is in your tables, but that will fix the problem.